# Can't Access Netgear WiFi Range Extender via www.mywifiext.net

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-extender, netgear-router

I have a [Netgear EX7300](https://mywifiexthelp.net/netgear-ex7300/) wireless Extender and I am having trouble getting to its initial configuration page.

The instructions to configure the device are:

Power on the device.
Connect a computer to the device with cat5 cable.
In a browser go to [http://www.mywifiext.net](https://mywifiexthelp.net/www-mywifiext-net/) and follow the onscreen directions.
The problem is, Visiting http://www.mywifiext.net in any browser results in a page not found and or page timeout.

Comment: Try to be more specific: are you connected to other network in the same time? How looks network configuration in your device?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because your extender got a different IP than 192.168.1.250 to which that domain resolves. You can access your extender directly by its assigned IP, but first you need to find it. You can do it using nmap:

```
nmap 192.168.1.*
```

This will scan all the IPs in the 192.168.1 subnet.

In the results look for the following fingerprint:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
5000/tcp open  upnp
7777/tcp open  cbt
8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook
```

Then just paste the IP in your browser's address bar.